# Cannot build Azure Data Factory project in VS 2015

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-data-factory

I cannot build my Azure Data Factory project in Visual Studio 2015 (Update 3).

I'm getting this error:

```
 Error    The "ADFCompilerTask" task failed unexpectedly.

System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. --->

System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))   
 at EnvDTE.Project.get_FileName()  
 at Microsoft.VSAuthoring.SDK.BuildSystem.JsonCompilerTask.get_ProjectHierarchy()
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.DataFactoryStudio.DataFactoryProject.ProjectSystem.ADFCompilerTask.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean  includeTaskCanceledExceptions)    
 at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    
 at Microsoft.VSAuthoring.SDK.BuildSystem.JsonCompilerTask.Execute()    
 at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
 at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
 ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotImplementedException: Not implemented (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004001 (E_NOTIMPL))    
 at EnvDTE.Project.get_FileName()    
 at Microsoft.VSAuthoring.SDK.BuildSystem.JsonCompilerTask.get_ProjectHierarchy()
 at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.DataFactoryStudio.DataFactoryProject.ProjectSystem.ADFCompilerTask.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()<---
```

In my project I have several datasets/pipeline/linked services defined. All of them could be deployed by copying into Azure Portal, so it does not look like validation issue.

I've tried reinstalling Azure DataFactory Tools, but it didn't help.

I work on Windows 7 using Visual Studio 2015 Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3,   Azure Data Lake Tools 2.2.5000 and Azure DataFactory Tools 0.9.3527.2 .

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to have a guess at this...

I suspect you'll have an attribute defined somewhere in your JSON in VS that is the wrong case. Especially if all the time slice validation is fine.

For example:

```
"isPaused": true,           // Correct
"pipelineMode": "Scheduled" //Correct
```

VS

```
"ispaused": true, 
"pipelinemode": "Scheduled"
```

As crazy as this sounds. Not all JSON elements get fully validated by Visual Studio and as your getting an exception that's not implemented this could be it. The ADFv1 schema's in VS are incomplete.

Search your JSON for green underlining!

Plus the Azure portal is a little more tolerant of the case sensitivity issues and if you copy and paste certain things into the portal it autocorrects them prior to deployment.

Failing that, try in it Visual Studio 2017 and see if its more helpful with the error handling.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! That's really was my issue - I had 'Name' instead of 'name' in several pipelines.

Comment: Lol. Awesome. Experience prevailed. Thanks for the bounty :-)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the answer above.  I had a similar problem but couldn't find any case issues with my JSON.  What I did find however was that when I loaded each component into the Visual Studio editor, I got notifications that I had corrupted line ends in two of my pipeline definition files - LF instead of CR/LF.

I let VS correct those line terminators, re-saved and deployed and all worked as it should have.

Thought I'd just mention it since the issue isn't always visually apparent in the editor screen.